# Could not load Joint_state_controller because the type was not specified error while roslaunch

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying to launch a robot on a world in gazebo 9 using roslaunch. While doing so I have been facing the following error and can not understand the reason behind it.

```
[ERROR] [1562704670.507021295, 1.372000000]: Could not load controller 'Joint_state_controller' because the type was 
not specified. Did you load the controller configuration on the parameter server (namespace: 
'/spider/Joint_state_controller')?
[ERROR] [1562704671.508187, 2.241000]: Failed to load Joint_state_controller
```

Here is my control launch file,

```
 <launch>

 <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
 <rosparam file="$(find spider_control)/config/spider_control.yaml" command="load"/>

 <!-- load the controllers -->
 <node name="controller_spawnner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
  output="screen" ns="/spider" args="joint_1_1_position_controller
                  joint_1_2_position_controller
                                      joint_1_3_position_controller
                                      joint_2_1_position_controller
                                      joint_2_2_position_controller
                                      joint_2_3_position_controller
                                      joint_3_1_position_controller
                                      joint_3_2_position_controller
                                      joint_3_3_position_controller
                                      joint_4_1_position_controller
                                      joint_4_2_position_controller
                                      joint_4_3_position_controller
                                      joint_5_1_position_controller
                                      joint_5_2_position_controller
                                      joint_5_3_position_controller
                                      joint_6_1_position_controller
                                      joint_6_2_position_controller
                                      joint_6_3_position_controller
                                      joint_7_1_position_controller
                                      joint_7_2_position_controller
                                      joint_7_3_position_controller
                                      joint_8_1_position_controller
                                      joint_8_2_position_controller
                                      joint_8_3_position_controller
                                      Joint_state_controller"/>

    <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
    <node name="rob_st_pub" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="robot_description" to="robot_description" />
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/spider/joint_states" />

  </node>
```

I am using ros-melodic with gazebo9. Can anyone please help me in finding the reason behind this error. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328070/could-not-load-joint_state_controller-because-the-type-was-not-specified-error-while-roslaunch/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry, the answer was simple, I kind of made a typo when loading the joint_state_controller in my control launch file. Instead of joint_state_controller, i wrote Joint_state_controller and that typo has caused the error.

---

Originally posted by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) with karma: 96 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2